# How can I edit my legend to match my colored groups in geom_dotplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am making a 2 group dot plot comparing each group for their ability to achieve a certain percentage of 4 different outcomes. Right now I have my graph exactly how I want it showing 2 colors (one for each group) and the mean plus standard deviation in black. My problem is my legend is showing the mean dots as the 2 different groups and I want it to show the group color dots. Any idea how I can fix it without having to change the mean to the color of the groups? The graph and code are attached. Thanks!

```
####GG Plot Package
library(ggplot2)

####Using tapply function
perc = read.csv("sealedvsunsealed.csv", header=TRUE)
perc
percmean <- tapply(perc$Percentage, list(perc$Group, perc$Hydrogels), mean) 
percsd <- tapply(perc$Percentage, list(perc$Group, perc$Hydrogels), sd) 
percmean
percsd

####Subseting the data (which function)
GI <- perc[which(perc$Hydrogels == 'Successful \nInjection'),]
A <- perc[which(perc$Hydrogels == 'Aggregation\nObserved'),]
CA <- perc[which(perc$Hydrogels == 'Cylindrical \nAggregates'),]
CLA <- perc[which(perc$Hydrogels == 'Fully Fills\nChannel'),]

GI
A
CA
CLA

####Create an ANOVA table
GI.aov <- aov(Percentage ~ Group, data = GI)
A.aov <- aov(Percentage ~ Group, data = A)
CA.aov <- aov(Percentage ~ Group, data = CA)
CLA.aov <- aov(Percentage ~ Group, data = CLA)

####Conduct a Tukey's multiple comparision procedure
TukeyHSD(GI.aov)
TukeyHSD(A.aov)
TukeyHSD(CA.aov)
TukeyHSD(CLA.aov)

####Grouped Dot Plot with stats added

vF = ggplot(perc, aes(x=factor(perc$Hydrogels, level = level_order), y=Percentage, fill=perc$Group)) +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center', position = position_dodge(0.7))+
  theme(legend.position = "right",  legend.title = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        axis.text = element_text(size = rel(1.5)),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = rel(1.5)))
vF

vF +  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom ="point", shape=18, size=4, position = position_dodge(0.7)) +         
  stat_summary(fun.ymin=function(x)(mean(x)-sd(x)), 
               fun.ymax=function(x)(mean(x)+sd(x)),
               position = position_dodge(0.7),
               colour = "black",
               geom="errorbar", width=0.3, size=1)+
  labs(x = NULL)
```

[Data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YwuQ2HaXCUcETh1HX2xQKDI1J9DNk182)

[Graph showing correct layout but incorrect legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7noB.png)

Comment: Hi Carlos and welcome to SO! Instead of a link to your data could you post the result of `dput(head(perc, 10))` at the end of your question? Also, most of the code you posted seems irrelevant to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Note you are missing level_order from your code, i guessed it from your plot

```
level_order = levels(perc$Hydrogels)[c(4,1,2,3)]
```

If you can do without the legend for the mean (i.e the diamond), you can just do:

```
vF +  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom ="point", shape=18, size=4, 
position = position_dodge(0.7),show.legend=FALSE) +
new_scale_color()+         
  stat_summary(fun.ymin=function(x)(mean(x)-sd(x)), 
               fun.ymax=function(x)(mean(x)+sd(x)),
               position = position_dodge(0.7),
               colour = "black",
               geom="errorbar", width=0.3, size=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! This was exactly what i needed.

Comment: Glad it helped! If you are satisfied with the answer, you can accept it and/or upvote it to signify to other people that this post is solved. More information on this link: stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Have a great weekend :)